# elementary OS update schedule

Tags: kernel

Does elementary OS stay up-to-date with Linux kernel like with Ubuntu 16 LTS updates?

Answer (score 2):

elementary Loki 0.4.1 utilizes the hardware enablement stack provided by Ubuntu Destkop 16.04LTS. Currently, this is shipping kernel 4.13.  Elementary installs will receive kernel patches (eg, for the recent CPU CVEs) when Ubuntu does.

If you already have Elementary installed, you can always run the following command to see what kernel you're running:

```
uname -r
```

For more on the HWE stack, see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack